# SDL_RenderDrawPoint vs setPixel function

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

Is either an obviously better choice? I have things set up with a setPixel function at the moment, and I want to know if I should change everything to RenderDraw functions.

Here's my setPixel function for reference.

```
void setPixel(SDL_Surface* surface, int X, int Y, Uint32 Color){

  Uint8* pixel = (Uint8*)surface->pixels;
  pixel += (Y * surface->pitch) + (X * sizeof(Uint32));
  *((Uint32*)pixel) = Color;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like `SDL_RenderDrawPoint()` takes a color. But couldn't you just replace your function with a macro that calls `SDK_RenderDrawPoint()` and profile it that way to see if it's faster?

Comment: +1 for profiling. However, usually, in real world applications you would not set single pixels *at all* (or at the very least, *only* if you *really* want to draw just one pixel).

Comment: OT: Consider using `BytesPerPixel` instead of `sizeof(Uint32)`.

Comment: I've been comparing speeds and it seems the setPixel function I have is a few times faster. When I set it to randomize the color some of the advantage is lost, but setPixel still comes out on top. The function for changing the RenderDraw color is SDL_SetRenderDrawColor()

Comment: @TakingItCasual What exactly are you trying to do? Draw a pixel onto something other than the screen, or trying just draw a pixel on the screen? If the last one is the case, I'm surprised the `setPixel()` function is faster as you would have to set the pixel, create the SDL_Texture from the SDL_Surface and the then render that SDL_Texture.